# What editor do you use for OpenLaszlo coding?

Tags: editor, openlaszlo

I'm new to developing in OpenLaszlo, and have tried Eclipse (hoping for decent code completion), but found it far too heavy for my tastes. fell back to using Textmate, but the bundle for OpenLaszlo is terribly out of date.

Any suggestions? or should I just roll up my sleeves and write a new bundle for Textmate?

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [SpketIDE](http://www.spket.com/) as an Eclipse plugin. It has some code completion, good syntax highlighting.

Comment: Back when I was doing some Laszlo development (about 2 years ago), this was pretty much the only viable option for Eclipse-based Laszlo development. It's a pretty good IDE for regular JavaScript too

Comment: Yes, Spket still seems to be the best option at the moment - if you fall for Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I use VIM for this. The VIM mode that ships with OpenLaszlo recognizes both the XML tags and the embedded JavaScript. Of course, if you're not already a VIM user, it's a big project to dive in.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a texteditor or XML editor with support for XSD schema, you can generate a custom XSD file of your application using this [OpenLaszlo Schema Generator](http://code.google.com/p/openlaszlo-schemagenerator/) tool. The tool uses Ant to generate the schema file, which then can be used by the editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

We used Visual Studio. And we used it just as a great XML editor.
I also used Notepad2 because it is very lightweight and has syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Notepad++ with the XML language chosen (since Open Laszlo is basically just XML and javascript). Simple, but effective and free.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have added it otherwise, but since its arch-enemy VI(m) was mentioned:

[Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)

is worth listing. :)

Without knowing much about OL, I am pretty sure one of gazillions of modes it has provides some level of support for your editing needs.

Comment: There's a [bit of information on Emacs configuration available in the OpenLaszlo wiki](http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/Editing_LZX#Emacs), but that information has been added 6-7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing in OpenLaszlo since 2006. I currently use NotePad++ with .lzx files set to be interpreted as XML files, this allows the code to be highlighted well in different colours for the different parts that make up OpenLaszlo code (XML nodes, JavaScript/AS3, etc.).

You can find NotePad++ at: 
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

it is free.

I just test my application by loading it into a web browser page.